# Run express middleware for all routes except that are starting with /api/v1

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, express

I know I can create a catchall route say

```
app.get(/^((?!\/api/v1\/).)*$/, (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build', 'index.html'));});
```

Comment: What is the error? It is not working correctly?

Comment: the point is i want ignore /api/v1 from my routes ! My code not working

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore `/api/v1` path use

```
/^((?!\/api\/v1).)*$/
```

Example

```
app.get(/^((?!\/api\/v1).)*$/, (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build', 'index.html'));});
```

and for the ignoring `/api/v1/`

```
/^((?!\/api\/v1\/).)*$/
```

Example

```
app.get(/^((?!\/api\/v1\/).)*$/, (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build', 'index.html'));});
```

```js
console.log(/^((?!\/api\/v1).)*$/.test('/api/v1'));
console.log(/^((?!\/api\/v1).)*$/.test('/api/example'));
```

Comment: @bokino12 what exactly do you want? Test for the `/api/v1` returns false if you are using `/^((?!\/api\/v1).)*$/` regex. So what's wrong?